# Difference of two standard Brownian motions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

How can one prove that with probability 1 $X(t)=Y(t)$  for infinitely many values of $t\in [0, \infty)$ , where $\{X (t); t \geq 0\}$ and $\{Y (t); t \geq 0\}$ are independent, standard Brownian motions? In a previous step we are asked to show that $Z(t) = X(t) - Y(t)$ is a Brownian motions with zero drift and volatility parameter 2t.

This is just a practice problem as I prepare for my exam.

Comment: Since you showed $X-Y$ is a Brownian motion, all you need is the fact that Brownian motion is recurrent. Do you know how to show that?

Comment: @Ian Is that to show that the time it takes $Z(t)$ to hit zero is finite? If so, I think I found an answer I can follow at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098741/proof-that-a-standard-brownian-motion-visits-zero-infinitely-often-at-the-beginn. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You know that $Z(t) = X(t) - Y(t)$ and hence $\hat{W}(t) = \frac{Z(t)}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a standard Brownian motion. It follows from the law of iterated logarithm that

$$\overline{lim}_{t \to \infty} \frac{ \hat{W}_t}{
\sqrt{2t \ln \ln t} } = 1$$
and
$$\underline{lim}_{t \to \infty} \frac{\hat{W}_t}{
\sqrt{2t \ln \ln t} } = -1.$$
Hence $\hat{W}(t) = 0$ for infinitely many values of $t$, q.e.d.

Comment: Thank you for this different approach. I'm not familiar with the law of iterated logarithms, however.