# set of zeros on brownian motion is unbounded

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a brownian motion.  Show that the set $S=\{t: W_t=0 \}$ is unbounded with probability one.

My attempt:  Suppose that there is a set $A$ with positive measure such that $S$ is bounded.  We know that brownian motion is a strong markov process so I'd assume we try to make some sort of stopping time to help us.  For example, $\sup\{t: W_t=0\}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that a standard Brownian motion visits zero infinitely often at the beginning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098741/proof-that-a-standard-brownian-motion-visits-zero-infinitely-often-at-the-beginn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that's not true. We will have there exists $s>0$, such that with positive probability, $W_t$ won't hit zero after time $t=s$, i.e., $$\mathbb{P}^0(W_t\neq 0 \text{ for any }t\ge s)>0.$$
Note that using simple Markov property, the left hand side equals
$$\mathbb{E}^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{W_s}(W_t\neq 0 \text{ for any }t\ge 0)).$$
Now for any $x$, (for simplicity we assume $x>0$)
$$\mathbb{P}^{x}(W_t\neq 0 \text{ for any }t\ge 0)=\lim_{M\uparrow \infty}\mathbb{P}^{x}(\text{hit }M\text{ before hit }0)=\lim_{M\uparrow \infty}\frac{x}{M}=0.$$
Hence $$\mathbb{P}^0(W_t\neq 0 \text{ for any }t\ge s)=\mathbb{E}^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{W_s}(W_t\neq 0 \text{ for any }t\ge 0))=0,$$
which leads to a contradiction.

Comment: What is $P^{W_s}$ and $P^{x}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^x$ is the law of Brownian motion starting at $x$. $\mathbb{P}^{W_s}$ is a composite function. We can write this as $\mathbb{P}^x|_{x=W_s}$ .

Comment: alright, thanks