# Ito diffusion crosses initial value infinitely many times?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider the stochastic process $Y_t=y+\int_0^t\sigma(Y_s)dW_s$ where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion. It is well known that if $\sigma(y)=\sigma >0$ constant we have that [$Y_t$ crosses $y$ infinitely many times in any arbitrarily small interval of time $(0,\varepsilon]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098741/proof-that-a-standard-brownian-motion-visits-zero-infinitely-often-at-the-beginn). I think that if $|\sigma(y)|>0$ and $\sigma$ satisfies the linear growth (i.e. $|\sigma(z)|\leq D(1+|z|)$ for some $D>0$)  and locally Lipschitz (i.e. $|\sigma(x)-\sigma(z)|\leq C_n|x-z|$ for all $|x|,|z|\leq n$ for some sequence $C_n$) conditions, then it is true that $Y_t$ crosses $y$ infinitely many times as above, like a Brownian motion. Intuitively, I would say that if $\varepsilon$ is small enough we have
$$Y_t\approx y+\sigma(y)W_t,\,t \in [0,\varepsilon]$$
and the property holds. Is there a reference for this that provides a formal proof (if it is true, of course)?

Comment: The conditions on $\sigma$ imply that $Y_t$ is defined for all $t>0\,.$ This includes that $\langle Y\rangle_t=\int_0^t\sigma^2(Y_s)\,ds<\infty$ for all $t>0\,.$ By the Dambis-Dubins-Schwarz theorem $Y_{T_t}$ is a Brownian motion where $T_t$ is the inverse of $t\mapsto \langle Y\rangle_t\,.$ Since $\langle Y\rangle_t$ is strictly increasing this inverse is also strictly increasing and we should be done because $Y_t=B_{\langle Y\rangle_t}$ where $B$ is the BM I mentioned.

Comment: Hello @KurtG., thank you very much for the hint. I am now checking (Karatzas, Shreve; 4.6. p. 134). Would you say that equation (4.17) is what I am looking for?

Comment: In my KS 2nd ed. it is $M_t=B_{\langle M\rangle_t}$ just in the DDS theorem on p. 174. I am sure you will make your way with those hints.

Comment: Ok I have another edition but it's that one. Thank you very much again @KurtG.