# How to Contain a Brownian Motion Between 2 Points?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

**I am interested in learning about if it is possible to mathematically define a Brownian Motion such that it can ONLY take values between two points** $a$ **and** $b$.

**Part 1: Definition**

Consider a Wiener Process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process):

A Wiener process $W(t)$, $t \in [0, \infty)$, is a real-valued continuous-time stochastic process that satisfies the following properties:

1. $W_0 = 0$
2. $W$ has independent increments: for every $t > 0$, the future increments $W_{t+u} - W_t$, $u \geq 0$, are independent of the past values $W_s$, $s < t$.
3. $W$ has Gaussian increments: $W_{t+u} - W_t$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $u$, i.e., $W_{t+u} - W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, u)$.

Thus, in general:

$$W(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{t-1} (W_i - W_{i-1})$$
$$(W_i - W_{i-1}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, dt)$$

**Part 2: Simulating a Basic Process**

Here is my attempt to simulate a Wiener Process in the R programming language:

```
library(ggplot2)

n <- 1000  # Number of steps
dt <- 1/n  # Time step

dW <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(dt))
W <- cumsum(dW)


df <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 1000, length.out = n), Wiener = W)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = Wiener)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(title = "Wiener Process", x = "Time", y = "Value") + theme_bw()

print(p)
```

[image]

**Part 3: Manually Forcing a Brownian Motion to stay between two points:**

For example, imagine a coin where the probability of success itself evolves as a stochastic process. That is, the probability of getting heads on the $n_{th}$ turn depends on the history of the previous flips according to a Wiener Process. In this case, I would have to define a Wiener Process between $0$ and $1$.

From a programming perspective, I think this might be possible: Every time the Wiener Process takes a value of $0$ or $1$, you can "force" it to take a value of 0.01 or 0.99 and resume the simulation:

```
n <- 1000  # Number of steps
dt <- 1/n  # Time step

dW <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = sqrt(dt))

W <- numeric(n)
W[1] <- 0.5  # Start in the middle of the interval [0, 1]

# Generate the Wiener process
for (i in 2:n) {
  W[i] <- W[i-1] + dW[i]
  
  # If the process hits 0 or 1, reset to 0.01 or 0.99 respectively
  if (W[i] <= 0) {
    W[i] <- 0.01
  } else if (W[i] >= 1) {
    W[i] <- 0.99
  }
}


df <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 1, length.out = n), Wiener = W)


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = Wiener)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Bounded Wiener Process", x = "Time", y = "Value") +
  theme_bw()


print(p)
```

[image]

**Part 4: Reflected Brownian Motion**

I found this link (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflected_Brownian_motion) which looks that it might be possible to "bound" a Brownian Motion (quoting the Wikipedia Page):

*A* $d$*-dimensional reflected Brownian motion* $Z$ *is a stochastic process on* $\mathbb{R}^d_+$ *uniquely defined by:*

- *a* $d$-*dimensional drift vector* $\mu$,
- *a* $d \times d$ *non-singular covariance matrix* $\Sigma$
- *a* $d \times d$ *reflection matrix* $R$.

*Where*:

- $X(t)$ *is an unconstrained Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and variance* $\Sigma$
- $Z(t) = X(t) + R Y(t)$

*Such that:* $Y(t)$ *a* $d$-*dimensional vector where:*

- $Y$ *is continuous and non-decreasing with* $Y(0) = 0$,
- $Y_j$ *only increases at times for which* $Z_j = 0$ for $j = 1,2,...,d$,
- $Z(t) \in \mathbb{R}^d_+$, $t \geq 0$.

But, from the above text, it seems like $Z(t) = X(t) + R Y(t)$ is the general form for a "constrained" (i.e. reflected) Brownian Motion - however, within this formulation, I am not sure which boundaries (i.e. values of a,b) this Brownian Motion will be contained within. Furthermore, I am not sure how the matrix $R$ needs to be defined such that the Brownian Motion lies between $(a,b)$.

**My Question:** How can I mathematically define the Wiener Process such that the range can only be between two numbers $a$ and $b$?

Thanks!

**Note:** Just to clarify - I want to ensure that the Brownian Motion NEVER exceeds a value of $a,b$  ... I am not interested in the concept of the "Brownian Bridge"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) where the Brownian Motion takes a value of 0 at time=0 and time=T.

Comment: If things prove to be difficult, maybe simply have the Brownian motion be unrestricted, and simply figure out whenever the particle passes through the limits, and reflect the motion across the limits?

Comment: @ naturallyInconsistent: thank you for your reply! I will look into this!

Comment: From the quoted Wiki article on reflected Brownian motion you know how to confine the process such that $Z>0$. For confinement such that $Z>a$ you just need to add a translation. (E.g. above change the condition to "$Y_j$ only increases at times for which $Z_j = a$" and so forth.) For an additional confinement $Z<b$ you need a second reflection condition (translated and mirrored, of course (e.g. "$Y_j$ only decreases at times for which $Z_j = b$" etc.)).

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: For reference, though, you're looking for *two-sided reflected Brownian motion* (or less frequently, *doubly reflected Brownian motion*). There is ample literature available, now that you know the name of what you're interested in.

Comment: This is a slight modification of a Brownian bridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider taking $Y_t = \frac{e^{X_t}}{1 + e^{X_t}}$ where $X_t$ is an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process. Then $X_t$ would have natural interpretation as a log odds prior whose long term limit is normally distributed at zero, and $Y_t \in [0,1]$ would have natural interpretation as a probability.

Through the Ito Lemma, you could recover the SDE for $Y_t$ in terms of the Weiner process, if you needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will look into this! In this Ornstein Uhlenbeck process, what happens when the process makes contact with the boundaries (0,1)?

Comment: There is no special accounting for boundaries. The further away the OU process $X_t$ gets away from zero, the more likely the next step will be towards zero. This way, the long term average is a stationary normal distribution. It is the transformation $Y_t$ that achieves the $[0,1]$ bounds that you seek.

Comment: @ Mark: Sorry, my apologies. For the transformed process $Y_t$, do we know what happens when it makes contact with the boundaries $(0,1)$? Do we need to further define some collision conditions?

Comment: No contact can be made, since $Y_t = 0$ implies $X_t = -\infty$, (and $Y_t = 1 \implies X_t = \infty)$ which cannot be actualized for any sample path.

Comment: @ Mark: Thank you for your reply! So in naive terms, the transformed process "bounces around" between (0,1) ... but has diminishing probabilities of  exactly reaching (0,1) ?

Comment: Yeah. If you simulate it and play around with the parameters $\sigma$ and $\theta$ of the $X_t$, you will understand it very quickly.

Comment: @ Mark: I have tried to use the advice you have given me to further understand these concepts. Here is my attempt: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4834748/simulating-a-function-that-is-naturally-contained-within-an-interval-a-b . Can you please take a look at this if you have time? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

The most natural way to force the Wiener process $W$ to stay in the interval $[0,1]$ is via conditioning. In other words, you consider a new process $\hat{W}$ which is $W$ conditioned on $W_t \in [0,1]$ for all $t$. (This can be rigorously done using [Doob's h-transform](https://linbaba.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/doob-h-transforms/)). This process is solution to the SDE
$$d\hat{W}_t = dW_t + \pi \cot(\pi \hat{W}_t)dt.$$
Notice the drift is $+\infty$ when $\hat{W}_t = 0$ forcing the process to increase and similarly when $\hat{W}_t = 1$.

To simulate it, either discretize the SDE or even simpler: knowing the value $\hat{W}_{t_i}$, to get $\hat{W}_{t_{i+1}}$, keep generating random variables $Z$ with distribution $N(0,t_{i+1}-t_i)$ until $\hat{W}_{t_i} + Z \in [0,1]$; this will be $\hat{W}_{t_{i+1}}$.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Is this possible for any interval (a,b) or is it only  passible for (0,1)? Is what you have written considered as a "reflected Brownian motion"? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob everything still works the same. The only change compared to above is the SDE which should now read (if I'm not mistaken) $$d\hat{W}_t = dW_t + \frac{\pi}{b-a} \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{b-a}(\hat{W}_t-a)\right) dt.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I am trying to learn more about all this! Please feel free to share any (gently) references on these topics! Much appreciated!

Comment: What happens when this transformed process makes contact with the boundary (a,b)?

Comment: @stats_noob If a Wiener process touches the boundary of $(a,b)$, it will exit the interval with probability 1. This is a generalization of the zero crossing theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098741/proof-that-a-standard-brownian-motion-visits-zero-infinitely-often-at-the-beginn 

So given that the conditioning rule here is correct, no sample path will ever actually make contact with the boundary.