# A characterization of the perfect sets in the Cantor set.

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

I've the following problem that gives a characterization of the perfect sets in the Cantor set.

A subset $P\subseteq 2^{\omega}$ is perfect if and only if it is homeomorphic to $2^{\omega}$.

Show that if $P$ is homeomorphic to $2^{\omega}$ then $P$ is perfect it's simple. But for the other implication I can't think of anything.

Does anyone have any hint?

Comment: Near-duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073141/compact-hausdorff-spaces-w-o-isolated-points-and-having-countable-bases-consisti

Comment: Oh! Of course, thank you very much Eric.